# Non existent dweller

Tags: fallout-shelter

My dweller who was training their intelligence has turned invisible and I cannot move him to another room, all I can adjust his equipment but that is it.

Comment: Have you tried exiting and launching the game again? Or rebooting your device?

Comment: You could try rushing nearby production rooms until they fail and let the incident spread to the room and kill the glitched character.